# Unable to create indexes in Sphinx after an emergency server restart [Can't create TCP/IP socket]

Tags: mysql, tcp, sphinx

I'm trying to execute the command in the Windows console:
C:\SphinxSearch\bin\indexer --all --config C:\SphinxSearch\sphinx.conf

But I get an error:
ERROR: index 'indexname': sql_connect: Can't create TCP/IP socket
(10093) (DSN=mysql://root:***@localhost:3306/test).

A data source is mysql. Before the server restart everyone works fine. 
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same error 10093. It's a [windows error code](http://www.sockets.com/err_lst1.htm#WSANOTINITIALISED) by the way. In my case it occurs when trying to run the indexer through the system account via a scheduled task. If I'm running it directly as administrator, there's not a problem.

According to the site above:

> Either your application hasn't called WSAStartup(), or WSAStartup() failed, or--possibly--you are accessing a socket which the current active task does not own (i.e. you're trying to share a socket between tasks).

In my case I'm thinking it might be the last one, some security problem due to user SYSTEM being used in my scheduled task. I was able to solve it by using my admin user instead: in the scheduled task, I set to use my local admin account with the option to "Run when user is logged on or not" and "Do not store password". I've also checked "Run with highest privileges". This seems to have done the trick as now my indexes are rotating on schedule.